# MySQL Field cannot be null error, although the field should allow the value to be null

Tags: php, mysql

I have the below statement to insert a record into a database. But with every record with `name` field as a empty value I get the following error:

```
Did not insert statement:Column 'name' cannot be null
```

Code:

```
function insertintomailinglist($user_id,$mail_list,$name,$surname,$company_name,$email_address,$number){
        if ($stmt = $this->link->prepare("INSERT INTO `mail_lists_list`(user_id, mail_lists_id, name, surname, company_name, email_address ,cell_number) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);")){ 
                // Bind the variables to the parameter as strings. 
                $stmt->bind_param("iisssss",$user_id,$mail_list,$name,$surname,$company_name,$email_address,$number);
                // Execute the statement.
                $stmt->execute();
                // Close the prepared statement.
                echo '<p> Did not insert statement:'.$stmt->error.' </p>';
                $stmt->close();
            }
    }
```

If I edit the mysql table, and set the default values to NULL, then the statement executes. But not without a default value...

Which is not right, as I know mysql fields should be allowed to have a NULL value.

What might be possible causes for this?

Comment: setting mysql column value to default NULL will help to get away with this problem, if you define column as NOT NULL, that means, no NULL values can be entered

Comment: It might help if you show us the metadata for the table

Answer (score 0):

The word `name` is a reserved word and should not be used as a column name.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html

So in order to use it you have to wrap that column name in backticks i.e. `name`

Comment: I changed name to first_name in the database, now I just get an error on the next field: Did not insert statement:Column 'surname' cannot be null